# This file is hidden - github error

Tags: git, github

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/attachment/7230109/3056274/

I am having the same problem as this guy, I was wondering how to track hidden files and their contents so that they can be committed.  Github seems to be globally blocking and ignoring my files (no matter which repo) when I try and drag and drop my files into it.

The problem started after I committed folders named lab1, lab2, lab3 through command line. I then later decided to remove them used

```
git rm -r lab1/ lab2/ lab3/
```

Now when I try to add all of the folders back to git, they are "detectless" and do not show up on `git status`, when I `git add` them
from my local folder even with changes to my `gitignore` file.

Comment: please provide steps how did you get there

Comment: it would better to link to the issue rather than screenshot, because he screenshot is not saying much. Also, at SO it is better to describe the issue fully here, because external lunk may expire, but you coul still link that issue

Answer (score 1):

First, you can check if this is a .gitignore issue by typing, from the root folder of your repo:

```
git check-ignore -v -- lab1/a_File_In_Lab1
```

Second, Make sure Lab1 does not have a .git subfolder in it: that would make it a nested repository, and you would need a `git rm --cached Lab1` (no trailing slash) to remove the gitlink recorded in your main repo.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick workaround, you may want to use **'Create new file'** option on GitHub.
I am having the same issue, but as the number of "hidden" files is manageable, I am simply "creating" the files on GitHub and Copy-Pasting the content inside of them.

This is obviously not a reliable solution we might prefer, but for now, it works!